# Do adipose births normally kill the host?

Tags: doctor-who

Adipose are only briefly mentioned in the Doctor Who universe. What I gathered was that adipose can under extreme circumstances convert an entire human body to adipose.

Does this imply that hosts normally survive? Where do the hosts normally come from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe they were normally prone to simply grow from the surplus adipose tissue (fat), which is why they seemed to work as a diet pill.  In unusual circumstances, they could make use of (convert) other tissue, which, done to a human, would kill them, if they simply used all available tissue.

Since they initially worked as a diet pill, and only later (after Matron Cofelia ordered the immediate birthing of all of them) caused death, I would guess that the hosts normally do survive, and it was only her action that precipitated all of the deaths.

This is just my conclusion based on the episodes, tho; I haven't seen any canon confirmation of their full life cycle.

See the Doctor Who wiki entry on [Adipose](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Adipose) for more info.

Comment: And I believe The Doctor made a comment that it wasn't a bad idea (exact quote not in my head). Which suggests that normally it was not a fatal process.

Comment: I believe you are thinking of his line while they are flying up to the ship... "Actually, as a diet plan, it sort of works." :) (From an [online script](http://who-transcripts.atspace.com/2008/transcripts/401_partnersincrime.html) of the episode.)

Comment: Yep. That's the line. Thanks for the link.

Comment: This is contradicted by "Turn Left" where the victims of Adipose infestation die.

Comment: @Richard I'll have to watch it again, but most of the bad things from 'Turn Left' relate to the absence of the doctor (due to the absence of Donna)... As I recall, the Adipose babies only started causing death by accident or when they were all triggered at once (see the '[March of the Adipose](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/March_of_the_Adipose)'.)  I'll re-watch and see if I can confirm.

Answer (score 1):

During the episode "[Turn Left](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/30-11.htm)", we see what happens when the Adipose are left to fully incubate;

> **WILF:** Well, America, they'll save us. It was on the news. They're going to send Great Britain fifty billion quid in financial aid. God
>   bless America. (Later, at mealtime -)
>
> **AMNN [on TV]:** **America is in crisis, with over sixty million reported dead. Sixty million people have dissolved into fat. And the
>   fat is walking.** People's fat has come to life and is walking through
>   the streets. And there are spaceships. There are reports of spaceships
>   over every major US city. The fat is flying. It's leaving. The fat
>   creatures are being raised into the air.

---

As to where their hosts *usually* come from, this is explained in The Stolen Earth. They have a "Breeding planet" known as [Adipose 3](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Adipose_3) where they typically incubate their young. It gets stolen by the Daleks which is the primary motivator for them invading Earth in the first place.

It's not clear whether they're parasitical on a pre-existing species or whether they have another way of breeding on their home planet.